# Retrieve data from H2 database through a Java service- Column debugging not found

Tags: java, mysql, database, jersey, h2

I am recently helping to test a Java service with H2 database. The H2 setting I am using is server mode and my url is `"jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=MySQL;"`

I realized there are some problems when loading mysql schema, so I followed this introduction (http://matthewcasperson.blogspot.com/2013/07/exporting-from-mysql-to-h2.html) and people's discussion here in stackoverflow to modify my schema dumped from MySQL.

The HttpPost from the Java service seems to be fine when I added a person/customer to the table. I can also see the customer being created in the H2 console. However, when I try to retrieve the customer data using HttpGet, I got this error message:

```
    {"message":"Column \"APPS0_.DEBUGGING\" not found; SQL statement:\n/* load one-to-many 
com.prduct.reward.db.Customer.apps */ select apps0_.customer_id as customer18_6_1_, apps0_.id as 
id3_1_, apps0_.id as id3_0_, apps0_.app_install_count as app2_3_0_, apps0_.app_key as app3_3_0_, 
apps0_.app_store_type as app4_3_0_, apps0_.app_store_live as app5_3_0_, apps0_.app_store_url as 
app6_3_0_, apps0_.create_date as create7_3_0_, apps0_.customer_id as customer18_3_0_, 
apps0_.debugging as debugging3_0_, apps0_.deleted as deleted3_0_, apps0_.icon_url as icon10_3_0_, 
apps0_.name as name3_0_, apps0_.os_type as os12_3_0_, apps0_.os_version_max as os13_3_0_, 
apps0_.os_version_min as os14_3_0_, apps0_.sdk_integration_info as sdk15_3_0_, apps0_.secret as 
secret3_0_, apps0_.update_date as update17_3_0_ from App apps0_ where apps0_.customer_id=? [42122-
174]","code":400}
```

The part I don't understand is that there is no debugging column either from the source code or any created table.

My code for retrieving customer is

```
public JSONObject retrieveCustomer() throws Exception { 
    String postUrl = http://localhost:8182/service/customer/customerKey;
    Client client = Client.create();
    WebResource webResource = client.resource(postUrl);
    final HTTPBasicAuthFilter authFilter = new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(adminLogin, adminpwd);
    client.addFilter(authFilter);
    ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);
    jsonResp = new JSONObject(response.getEntity(String.class));
    System.out.println(jsonResp02);
    return jsonResp;
}
```

The Java service is connected to the H2 (url: jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test), and the HTTP server listens for service requests is through the 8182 port.

Can somebody suggest me how to deal with this problem? I have been searching around for the past two days but still couldn't find a solution. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What's your problem? No debugging columns?

Comment: My problem is I couldn't get the customer result from HttpGet. There shouldn't be debugging columns and I don't know why the error message say that.

Comment: Well, the error message says: a query was run that was trying to read the debugging column that doesn't exist.

Comment: That's really odd. I checked the schema and the Java code and didn't find the debugging column. I was thinking if it related to H2 because I didn't face this problem when I ran it using my local MySQL database.